# Umbraco - when editor create content send email notification to admin

Tags: email, notifications, umbraco

Is it possible?
I am an admin. I want to be notified by email when editor (or writer or whom ever with the access) creates some content (e.g. enters some News in News document type).
And how?
I use Umbraco 7.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to code into Umbraco ContentService events.

The following should get you started.  It will be triggered whenever an item is published.

Be careful what you wish for though.  You may get a barrage of useless emails if somebody publishes a parent node along with all of its child nodes.

There are other events that you can hook into so please refer to documentation at https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Reference/Events/ContentService-Events-v7.

```
using Umbraco.Core;
using Umbraco.Core.Events;
using Umbraco.Core.Models;
using Umbraco.Core.Publishing;
using Umbraco.Core.Services;

namespace My.Namespace
{
    public class MyEventHandler : ApplicationEventHandler
    {

        protected override void ApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        {
            ContentService.Published += ContentServicePublished;
        }

        private void ContentServicePublished(IPublishingStrategy sender, PublishEventArgs<IContent> args)
        {
            foreach (var node in args.PublishedEntities)
            {
                 // Your code to send email here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Don't worry about "barraging", because one man writes one News each week, and the News is the only editable CMS, so... Anyway, I'll try it tomorrow and get back to you with the rating.

Comment: As usual, we have a problem with email server and nobody knows, so I'll have to wait for network guys to test this :(

Comment: However, I tried writing in log and it works excellent! Thank you, that was exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can either write your own custom code by creating some event handlers, which is what @wingyip has recommended, or you can use built-in Umbraco notification functionality.

For the second built-in option, please see all the steps here [on this post](http://nurhak-kaya.blogspot.com/2018/08/umbraco-notifications-save-and-send-for.html).